# How do I make an increment textbox loop show on different label with buttonclick

Tags: c#, button, textbox, label

I'm a freshman new to c# programming.
I'm trying to increment integer in textbox and show it on different label with every button click
This should be a simple task,but I've been stucking on this question for weeks,so I'm here to seek help
Any advice and suggestion will be great help.
Thank you for your help in advance.

This is what the final output should be look like:

[keyin the number you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxx3N.png)

[first button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRAmi.png)

[second button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6lsu.png)

[third button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ki4.png)...etc

Comment: Looks like you have your UI setup, already. If you are using Visual Studio then a double click on the button will wire up the `button_onclick` event method. In that method you will want to increment the integer value of what is in your `TextBox`. The best thing to do would be to create a class level `int` property. Increment that property everytime you click. Display this data by using the `Text` property of the `Label` and `TextBox`. That will get you started. Good Luck.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. One of the things about this site I'd that you are very unlikely to get an answer to a question in which you don't show the code you've tried. Here's a hint though, keep a boolean flag as a class member (called, for example, `useFirstLabel`). Use it to decide which label to update (and after each update, change its state (initially true, then false, then true...))

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- It looks like the top label holds the current and the bottom label holds the previous
- We can transfer the current to previous and calculate a new current
- The user will always type good input so we don't need to get too heavy into error checking

The following code implements the assumptions:

```
void incrementButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args){

  int current = int.Parse(topLabel.Text);
  int increment = int.Parse(incrementTextbox.Text);

  bottomLabel.Text = topLabel.Text;
  topLabel.Text = (current + increment).ToString();

}
```

Because you didn't post any code, the code above should be treated as pseudocode that demonstrates a concept; you will probably have to heavily modify it to meet your needs